# SP 2013 document library custom view webpart

Tags: web-part, document-library, dashboard

We have a requirement to display most recent uploaded file in a document repository in a separate view on the home page.

For example we have Document_Library_1 with files file_new, file_old1, file_old2... we need to have a custom custom view or dashboard on homepage, where the user can access the most recent reports.

[image]

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this, is custom webpart a solution or the standard view could be customized?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View on your Document Library. In the Library click in the top ribbon on Create a View.

Change the sort by Modified Date / Created Date depending on what you want to achieve.

Then change the sort order for ascending or descending.
In the end, go back on your HomePage and add a new WebPart using the Document Library.

Change the View from default to the View you have just created.
This should do the trick.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder structure in your library, don't forget to tick this option in your view settings, otherwise you won't get the latest files in a folder:

[image]